# Why does CreateCompatibleBitmap fail after about a thousand executions?

Tags: c++, bitmap

I am trying to write a screen capture/record application.  Here's the part of the code that captures the screen and saves it:

```
width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMAXTRACK)+8;
height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMAXTRACK)-8;

hwindowDC=GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
hwindowCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC,COLORONCOLOR);  

// create a bitmap
hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hwindowDC, width, height);
cout << " handle to newly created bitmap: " << hbwindow << "\n";

SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow); //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow
StretchBlt( hwindowCompatibleDC, 0,0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0,width,height, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !

src.create(height,width,CV_8UC4);   
src.empty();
GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC,hbwindow,0,height,src.data,(BITMAPINFO *)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS); 


DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC); 
DeleteObject(hbwindow);
```

After a thousand or so repetitions, my cout statement will show the newly created handle as 000000000000000 aka. NULL.  My app works fine until that point.
I am deleting the created DC and bitmap each time so there is no memory leak.  Task Manager also confirms there is no memory leak.  So what is happening?

Thank you for anyone who can assist in this.

Comment: You should be selecting objects out of your DC, then deleting the objects, then deleting the DC.

Comment: Though it sounds odd, try selecting the *old* bitmap back into your dc prior to deleting the dc and the bitmap (and just for absolute good measure, select the old back in, then delete hbwindow, then delete the compatible dc). Also,`ReleaseDC(hWindowDC)` at the end of this fiasco appears to be missing.

Comment: @JesseGood Remember. Delete what you Create, Release what you Get. **He *should* be Releasing the window DC, so you're right on that.**

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, I just realized that. Thanks. **Edit**: Yes, good point on that.

Comment: Always check return values and call `GetLastError` as appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the two problems were 1) you weren't releasing the DC obtained from the desktop window, and 2) you weren't selecting the original bitmap back into the compatible DC before deleting it. Both of these cause a GDI resource leak which will lead to the symptoms you describe.

Fixed code below:

```
width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMAXTRACK)+8;
height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMAXTRACK)-8;

hwindowDC=GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
hwindowCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC,COLORONCOLOR);  

// create a bitmap
hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hwindowDC, width, height);
cout << " handle to newly created bitmap: " << hbwindow << "\n";

// SAVE OLD BITMAP
HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow); //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow
StretchBlt( hwindowCompatibleDC, 0,0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0,width,height, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !

src.create(height,width,CV_8UC4);   
src.empty();
GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC,hbwindow,0,height,src.data,(BITMAPINFO *)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS); 

// RESTORE OLD BITMAP
SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hOldBmp);
DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC); 
DeleteObject(hbwindow);

// RELEASE WINDOW DC
ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hwindowDC);
```

You should also be doing proper error checking (as calls like `GetDC`, `CreateCompatibleDC` etc can fail and return NULL).

Comment: You sound like you know what you're talking about so I'm sure this is the answer.  But ReleaseDC does not take 1 argument.

Comment: Of course you're right :) Fixed in the answer. The perils of trying to do three things at once!

Comment: @user396483 You chose... wisely =) Remember, **Release** what you **Get**, and **Delete** what you **Create**. This applies to almost everything in GDI Windows work. (and of course, restore what you muck with if applicable). +1 to the answer btw.

Comment: **Detach** what you **Attach** ;P