# Memory leak with createDCFromHandle()/ createCompatibleDC()

Tags: python, winapi, memory-leaks, gdi+, win32gui

I am trying to capture screen using GDI, I found one code snippet and modified that as per my requirement. Here is the code[**EDIT**: code modified for simplicity]:

```
def getfunc():
        # grab a handle to the main desktop window
        hdesktop = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()

        # create a device context
        desktop_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hdesktop)
        img_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(desktop_dc)

        # create a memory based device context
        self.mem_dc = img_dc.CreateCompatibleDC()

        # create a bitmap object
        screenshot = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        screenshot.CreateCompatibleBitmap(img_dc, width, height)
        self.mem_dc.SelectObject(screenshot)


        # copy the screen into our memory device context
        try:
            self.mem_dc.BitBlt((destUpLeftX, destUpLeftY), (width, height), img_dc, (srcUpLeftX, srcUpLeftY),win32con.SRCCOPY)
        except :
            logger.debug("BitBlt failed")

        img_dc.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(hdesktop, desktop_dc)

        win32gui.DeleteObject(screenshot.GetHandle())


def delete(self):
        self.mem_dc.DeleteDC()
```

Now when I am trying to run this code, after exactly 80 iteration. I am getting errors saying createDCFromHandle failed or createCompatibleDC failed.

I look over for any solution at arrived at the following stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100028/createcompatibledc-fails-after-calling-it-exactly-4-984-times)

As per post, there is problem of memory leak,I modified my delete function as per suggestion. But I think still I am missing, any pointers for the same ?

Comment: Show a [mcve]. You certainly leak everything that you create in `getfunc` and hold in local variables.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan tried removing local variables, but still the same problem, any other pointers?

Comment: [mcve] please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are deleting `mem_dc` at a later point. `screenshot` (the bitmap) is still selected in `mem_dc` so the deletion of `screenshot` is delayed until `mem_dc`'s deletion. This can run in to problem depending on how the rest of the code is setup.

You can remove the risk by selecting the bitmap out of `mem_dc` as soon as possible. Below is an example of how that can be done.

Note that you have a limit of 10,000 GDI handles, so your code shouldn't fail after 80 iterations. The problem might be elsewhere.

```
hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
hdc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
memdc = win32gui.CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)
hbitmap = win32gui.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 100, 100)
oldbmp = win32gui.SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap)

win32gui.BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, 100, 100, hdc, 0, 0, win32con.SRCCOPY)

#use memdc here

win32gui.SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp)
win32gui.DeleteObject(hbitmap)
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc)
win32gui.DeleteDC(memdc)
```

---

*Alternate method*

Use `bits = GetBitmapBits` and get individual pixels using

```
p = (y * width + x) * 4
blue=bits[p+0]&0xFF
green=bits[p+1]&0xFF
red=bits[p+2]&0xFF
```

Example:

```
def foo(width, height):
    hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    hdc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hdc)
    memdc = dc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    bitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, width, height)
    oldbmp = memdc.SelectObject(bitmap)
    memdc.BitBlt((0,0), (width,height), dc, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    bits = bitmap.GetBitmapBits(False)
    memdc.SelectObject(oldbmp)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(bitmap.GetHandle())
    memdc.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc)
    return bits

width = 100
height = 100
bits = foo(width,height)

for y in range(0,10):
    for x in range(0,10):
        p = (y * width + x) * 4
        blu=bits[p+0]&0xFF
        grn=bits[p+1]&0xFF
        red=bits[p+2]&0xFF
        print("%02X%02X%02X " % (blu,grn,red), end='')
    print('')
```

Comment: screenshot = win32guiui.CreateCompatibleBitmap(img_dc, width, height), it given me error "the object is not a pyhandle object"

Comment: my bad, I made a typo here.. screenshot = win32gui.CreateCompatibleBitmap(img_dc, width, height) and the error is TypeError: The object is not a PyHANDLE object

Comment: thanks for the code, but I am unable to call GetPixel() on the memdc object now, as I need to read pixel value at few location.

Comment: That's because this code properly deletes `hbitmap` right away, and you probably call `win32gui.GetPixel` at a later point, so it fails as expected. You should call `win32gui.GetPixel` before `win32gui.SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp)`.

Comment: By the way, you can use `GetPixel` directly on desktop, no need for memory dc. If you need all the pixels, use `screenshot.GetBitmapBits(False)` to access all the bits.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer... but how do we access one location in that pixel array, once we have bitmap ?

Comment: The returned bits are `RGBQUAD` values, use `p = (y * width + x) * 4` to find the pixels.